# Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE + 5.2.0.Final, org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I have Exaption and after i search it in google there is no spsific solution fr this version of Hibernate and Spring.
Please Try to help if you can :)

Ok Thank you @M. Deinum i changed to hibrnate 5 and build new tomcat server its looking good and this is my log now: you see any more problems in my work?

**The console log:**

```
    יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Searcher' did not find a matching property.
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.36.0
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_92-b14
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Home\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Home\Documents\DropShiping\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Home\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Home\Documents\DropShiping\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Home\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Home\Documents\DropShiping\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\endorsed
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1255
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Home\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\xampp\php\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Users\Home\Documents\DropShiping\Framework\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 877 ms
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:06 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'searcher'
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
יונ 29, 2016 2:45:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7110 ms
```

**searcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Searcher-Servlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"> 
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" 
    /> <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> <property name="suffix" 
    value=".jsp" /> </bean> -->

<!-- DataSource -->
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SearcherDB" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.ImageEntity</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.ProductEntity</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.ProductRequestEntity</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.RequestEntity</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.SellerEntity</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.UserEntity</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- eCommerce -->
<beans:bean id="ecommerceDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.EcommerceImp">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="ecommerceService" class="com.searcher.service.EcommerceServiceImp">
    <beans:property name="ecommerceDAO" ref="ecommerceDAO">
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Image -->
<beans:bean id="imageDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.ImageImp">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="imageService" class="com.searcher.service.ImageServiceImp">
    <beans:property name="imageDAO" ref="imageDAO">
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Product -->
<beans:bean id="productDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.ProductImp">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="productService" class="com.searcher.service.ProductServiceImp">
    <beans:property name="productDAO" ref="productDAO">
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- ProductRequest -->
<beans:bean id="productRequestDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.ProductRequestImp">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="productRequestService"
    class="com.searcher.service.ProductRequestServiceImp">
    <beans:property name="productRequestDAO" ref="productRequestDAO">
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Request -->
<beans:bean id="requestDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.RequestImp">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="requestService" class="com.searcher.service.RequestServiceImp">
    <beans:property name="requestDAO" ref="requestDAO">
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Seller -->
<beans:bean id="sellerDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.SellerImp">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="sellerService" class="com.searcher.service.SellerServiceImp">
    <beans:property name="sellerDAO" ref="sellerDAO">
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- User -->
<beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.UserImp">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="userService" class="com.searcher.service.UserServiceImp">
    <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO">
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.searcher" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Searcher</groupId>
<artifactId>Searcher</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>



</dependencies>

<!-- Build -->
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
            <additionalProjectnatures>
                <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
            </additionalProjectnatures>
            <additionalBuildcommands>
                <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
            </additionalBuildcommands>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <!-- Old

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    -->   

</plugins>
</build>
<!--  Old 2
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
-->
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Searcher</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>searcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>searcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Why are you using a `hibernate4` transaction manager whilst using `hibernate5`? And why are you mixing hibernate 5.1.0 and 5.2.0... Never mix versions of a framework.

Comment: Make sure you don't have an old version of spring somewhere on your server... Looks like your tomcat has some old dependency somewhere.

Comment: hibrante 4 is from old try to fix it i'am changing it now and update the exaption, the 2 version of hibenate is both nost updated